# ImportError: cannot import name 'imshow'

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

unfortunalty I have not found a solution for this problem.

```
from imgutils import imshow
import cv2

img3 = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

plt.subplot(1,2,1); imshow(img)
plt.subplot(1,2,2); imshow(img3)
```

I get the following traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-8006396b3a04> in <module>
----> 1 from imgutils import imshow
      2 
      3 img3 = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
      4 
      5 plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

ImportError: cannot import name 'imshow'
```

I am working on a Mac OS X 10.11, with a anaconda environment, python 3.5.

I have search the web to the imgutils module and have not a module, which have a imshow function.

Any suggestions?

---

Update

```
from cv2 import imshow

img3 = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

plt.subplot(1,2,1); imshow(img)
plt.subplot(1,2,2); imshow(img3)
```

Traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-d01b4c235975> in <module>
      5 plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
      6 
----> 7 plt.subplot(1,2,1); imshow(img)
      8 plt.subplot(1,2,2); imshow(img3)

TypeError: Required argument 'mat' (pos 2) not found
```

Comment: did you mean `cv2.imshow(img)` instead of `imgutil.imshow`?

Comment: Use `from cv2 import imshow`.

Comment: Its not my code, its  a tutorial code. This is the issue. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`imgutils`**](https://github.com/dimatura/imgutils/tree/master/imgutils) does not seem to contain an `imshow` attribute (and therefore definitely not a function). It does not contain an `imshow` submodule, nor does it imports an `imshow` function in the `__init__.py` file: it basically reimports elements from the submodules like, but a fast search does not yield an `imshow` function.

You probably wan to use the `imshow` from the `matplotlib.pyplot` module, so you should replace:

```
from imgutils import imshow
```

with:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
```

This then imports the [**`cv2.imshow`** [pyplot-doc]](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.htmle) function.

Comment: That problem is, the code is from a tutorial and I have to run it. :)

Comment: @madik_atma: what tutorial?

Comment: @madik_atma: well unless it is a local package, there is no such `imshow`. But I am quite confident that by changing it, it will run.

Comment: I have run your suggestion. I got the following traceback and have edit the post

Comment: Hold on, did you import `pyplot` as well?

Comment: Yeah I am working at a jupyter notebook and at the top pyplot is imported. :)

Comment: Its working thank you. But why the instructor uses the imgutils?

Comment: @madik_atma: it could be a local package he/she made that *reimports* the `imshow` I guess, but I searched on the internet, and the one in `pip` is the linked one, and this can not work.